# Do Internet Standards Support Only ASCII E-mail Addresses?

Tags: database, email, unicode, standards, globalization

I'm creating a database for a global application that stores data in multiple written languages. This means I am storing a lot of double-byte Unicode strings for various fields. But when storing E-mail addresses, does the internet only recognize single-byte ASCII characters in the address? If so, I could cut the size of this field in half, which would be a big performance boost in this case.

Comment: Are you sure it would be a bug performance boost?

Comment: @SLaks: The E-mail Address field constitutes a large consumption of resources in this particular database, so cutting the size down would definitely help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RFC 3490](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3490) proposes the use of unicode characters in domain names (which obviously make up the second part of an email address). So it would be wise to support this.